# Change build behavior in XCode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there any way to change how XCode compiles my code without completely reprogramming the compiler? Specifically, I want to add a keyword that when used, will invoke a certain behavior for the program. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Comment: This sounds a bit too vague - can you provide more details or an example? Also, which programming language are we speaking about?

Comment: Ok, this is a little hard to explain, but here goes. What I'm trying to do is make something that you can put before a variable declaration that will make the variable accessible thru Interface Builder. So if you type something like "IBAccessible NSString *name" in a UIView subclass, you can then change that value with a text field in the IB Attributes panel when you create an instance of that view. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sounds like you should check out IBOutlets for connecting views via IB & look into bindings for other data types.

Comment: IBOutlet and IBAction are empty preprocessor definitions.  They mean nothing to the compiler.

Comment: The thing is, I want to be able to set the IVars via IB. Like in a UIView, you can set the background via a color chooser. I want to do something that would automatically generate and IB Plugin.

Comment: In order to do that, you have to create a plugin for Interface Builder which contains an inspector view for your object. IB's only interaction with the code is looking for IBOutlets and IBActions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compiler directives/macros like #define are one way you can go about this.  For example objective-c originally started out as [compiler directives and unix commands](http://www.computerworld.com.au/article/350272/z_programming_languages_objective-c/).

Likely what you want to do can be accomplished in a different way.  You might want to look into the template system that apple has for interface builder to allow you to add your own objects to IB.  Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49442/when-to-create-interface-builder-plug-in-for-custom-view) for more.